# JProgressBar not working as expected

Tags: java, swing, progress-bar, jprogressbar

I am trying to use this JProgressBar with a button. I set the visibility of the ProgressBar to true on click of the button and in the same code I call a webservice. Upon receipt of a response from the web service, I set the visibility of the progress bar to false.

Below is my code.

Please help me fix this. At present the ProgressBar appears only after teh response is received.

```
 JButton testAPI = new JButton("Test API");
    testAPI.setBounds(OFFSET_X + 80, OFFSET_Y + 140, 120, 30);
    testAPI.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            prg.setVisible(true);
            String apiKey = apiKeyText.getText();
            testAPI(apiKey);
        }
});
 add(testAPI);

protected void testAPI(String apiKey) {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(testQuery);
    sb.append("officialdharam@gmail.com");
    RestClient client = new RestClient();
    try {
        prg.setVisible(true);
        Response s = client.invoke(sb.toString(), HttpMethod.POST);
        prg.setVisible(false);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is executed on the EDT so the GUI can't repaint itself until the task is finished.

Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Progress Bars](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html) for a working example that uses a SwingWorker.

Also, read the tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information about the EDT.